# October CMS is not installing

Tags: octobercms

Can someone help?

I am trying to install this CMS, switched to PHP 7.3.
It still displays nothing when i try to run script:

http://mail1.softwr.ru/install_files/php/Installer.php
http://mail1.softwr.ru/install_files/php/

install.log doesn't contain any errors or smth like that.

Comment: maybe your server error reporting is off, try to enable it so it will show an error I guess

Comment: you better ask more general questions. Instead of using temporary links try to use stationary information. If someone will have a similar issue after 3 years, they should benefit from your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing something,

you don't have to call those file or folders directly.

If you look into the installer archive, you'll see that there's an `install.php` file and you have to go to https://your.site/install.php to install OctoberCMS.

[image]

Best,

Comment: Oh yes, you are right!!  I didn't upload instal.php
I did see it between trash like readme.md and .gitnore  :)

Comment: @Anufriy no problem ! glad to help you ! don't forget to make this +1 up to valid this answer :)